# Soldering ground plane top vs bottom

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, circuit-design, soldering

[image]I have a board that uses ground and vcc planes. If ground plane is on top layer and vcc is on bottom, should I solder on top layer ground pins and keep seperate from bottom layer? Or could I solder all pins on bottom...regardless of which layer planes exist in?

Comment: If you’re talking about through-hole components then the hole will fill with solder if the joint is made properly.  The question is valid though, since the power plane will tend to cool the through-plating which could result in solder not fully penetrating, so doing what you suggest may in fact be a good idea, although this is only likely to make a significant difference for high speed or moderate to high current situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience.

Solder top or bottom does not make a difference. If the solder forms a wetting filet surrounding the pin and on the pad, then it will work. It is desirable to have the solder wick up the pin inside the hole to reduce vibration effects.

Soldering to a ground plane is difficult. The photo shows the thermal spokes to the pad. It appears that the ground plane still pulled heat away preventing the solder from wicking through the hole.

I have found that increasing the temperature of the soldering iron can compensate for ground plane cooling. Practice on scrap until applying the soldering iron for a short time (2 to 3 sec) allows the solder to wick up through the hole. If you have to hold the soldering iron on for too long there is a risk of delamination or component damage.

Comment: It also usually a good idea to warm up the PCB pad for a second or two with the tip before also touching the component leg and apply solder. Chisel tips highly recommended when struggling with ground planes. But this is through-hole 2 layer so ground plane cooling is usually not a big problem.

Comment: I've noticed when soldering by hand that the near side gets soldered, then after a few moments the solder pool diminishes suddenly when it flows through to the other side. Then add a little bit more solder to get a slightly concave surface again, and the joint is good on both sides.

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing incomplete fill of the PTH barrel.  Depending on which IPC class rules you are using (if you're using them at all), incomplete fill is acceptable provided that you inspect the *amount* of fill and ensure that it is at least 50%, 75%, etc depending on class.  It might be easier to adjust your soldering parameters to ensure 100% fill.  The land on the solder destination side does *not* need to have solder coverage.

Comment: Any assembly house not following IPC class 3 these days will see themselves out of business pretty quick I think. Also anything that's remotely close to outdoor use ought to follow class 3.

Answer (score 4):

If the PCB is correctly made, then every hole is plated-through, meaning it doesn't matter electrically.

But taking proper though-hole soldering in account (as per IPC-A-610), then:

- Components are *always* soldered on the solder side.
- A correctly done solder joint covers the plating on the hole *on both sides*. This to prevent oxidation.
- A correctly done solder joint will climb up the component leg slightly *on both sides*.

The IC in your picture is not correctly soldered. Reasons for this could either be too little solder or a cold joint/no proper wetting.